# Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am using MPI to parallelise my code but I encounter the following error when I run my code:

```
Loading mkl-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading compilers-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading tbb-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading tbb-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading mpi-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
[d3051:28118:0:28118] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x7fff0025d810)
==== backtrace (tid:  28118) ====
 0 0x0000000000050b35 ucs_debug_print_backtrace()  ???:0
 1 0x00000000004171d0 MAIN__()  ???:0
 2 0x00000000004053e2 main()  ???:0
 3 0x0000000000022555 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
 4 0x00000000004052e9 _start()  ???:0
=================================
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
cpge               0000000000420DBA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.17.s  00002AFC24C82630  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
cpge               00000000004171D0  MAIN__                    318  tb_cpge.f90
cpge               00000000004053E2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002AFC251B3555  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
cpge               00000000004052E9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Here is my main code:

```
PROGRAM TB_HAMILTONIAN

USE MPI

USE HAML

IMPLICIT NONE

!!!Block: Parameter setting

!Parameters used in the main code
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)                   !Precision of the floating number
INTEGER :: i, j, k
INTEGER :: num_wan                                                     !Number of wannier function
INTEGER :: num_nrpt                                                    !Number of Wigner-Seitz grid point
INTEGER :: ios(2)                                                      !status of files
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: ndegen(:)                                      !Degeneracy of each Wigner-Seitz grid point
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: hr(:,:)                                 !Array to store Hamiltonian matrix information in 'wannier90_hr.dat' file
REAL (KIND=dp) :: rea_cons(3,3)                                        !Lattice constant of unit cell in real space
REAL (KIND=dp) :: rec_cons(3,3)                                        !Vectors of unit cell in reciprocal space
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tra(3)                                               !Array for transiting data
CHARACTER (LEN=100) :: stri
LOGICAL :: jud = .TRUE.
REAL (KIND=dp) :: alat                                                 !Scaling factor
!

!Parameters used in Berry Curvature Subroutine
INTEGER :: kb(3)                                                       !k point mesh for berry curvature
REAL (KIND=dp) :: eta                                                  !Resolution for the berry curvature
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_tb(:,:)                           !Array to store the extracted tight binding Hamiltonian matrix
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_kp(:,:)                              !Array to store the coordinate of k point
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evc(:,:)                          !Array to store the Eigen vector matrix
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evl(:)                               !Array to store the Eigen value
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kp(3)                                                !Array to store the coordinate of k point passing to the subroutine
REAL (KIND=dp) :: dk(3)                                                !Array to store the increment of k point along three axes
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fe                                                   !Fermi energy level
REAL (KIND=dp) :: er(2)                                                !Array to store the energy window for the berry curvature
REAL (KIND=dp) :: pi                                                   !Constant pi
REAL (KIND=dp) :: sa                                                   !Parameter Sigma in Laplace-Gauss Distribution function
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fq                                                   !Frequency of incident photo
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tp                                                   !Temperature in Fermi-Dirac distribution function
REAL (KIND=dp) :: hb                                                   !h_bar (eV*s)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: el                                                   !Electronvolt (Coulombs)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: th                                                   !Thickness of the system (Angstroms)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: cf                                                   !Coefficient
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp1(:,:)                            !Array to store the berry curvature at each k point on each processor
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp2(:,:)                            !Array to store the berry curvature at each k point on root processor
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp3(:,:)                            !Array to store the berry curvature at each k point from other processor
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: br(9)                                             !Array to store the total berry curvature along xx, xy, xz, yy, yz and xz components
!

!Paramters used in the timer
INTEGER :: cr, ti(2)                                                   !Variables for timer
REAL (KIND=dp) :: ra                                                   !Rate for timer
!

!Parameters used in MPI
INTEGER :: world_size, world_rank, ierr, irank                         !Variables for MPI
!

!!!END BLOCK: Parameter setting

!Initialising MPI
CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)
!

!Initialising timer
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count_rate=cr)
   ra = REAL(cr)
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(ti(1))
END IF
!

!Constatnt pi
pi = DACOS(-1.0d0)
!

!Reduced Planck constant
hb = 6.582119569d-16
!

!Electronvolt
el = 1.602176634d-19
!

!Reading and broadcasting all input parameters
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='wannier90.wout', STATUS='OLD', IOSTAT=ios(1))
   OPEN (UNIT=4, FILE='wannier90_hr.dat', STATUS='OLD', IOSTAT=ios(2))

   !Reading Lattice Constant in real space
   DO WHILE (ios(1) .EQ. 0)
      READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
      IF (TRIM(ADJUSTL(stri)) .EQ. 'Lattice Vectors (Ang)') THEN
          DO i = 1, 3, 1
             READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
             stri = ADJUSTL(stri)
             READ (UNIT=stri(4:), FMT=*) rea_cons(i,:)
          END DO
          EXIT
      END IF
   END DO
   !

   !Reading Vectors of unit cell in reciprocal space
   DO WHILE (ios(1) .EQ. 0)
      READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
      IF (TRIM(ADJUSTL(stri)) .EQ. 'Reciprocal-Space Vectors (Ang^-1)') THEN
         DO i = 1, 3, 1
            READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
            stri = ADJUSTL(stri)
            READ (UNIT=stri(4:), FMT=*) rec_cons(i,:)
         END DO
         EXIT
      END IF
   END DO
   !

   !Closing 'wannier90.wout' file
   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
   !

   !Reading number of wannier function and Wigner-Seitz grid point
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2))
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) num_wan
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) num_nrpt
   !

END IF
!

CALL MPI_BCAST(num_wan,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(num_nrpt,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

!Allocating the array to store the degeneracy of each Wigner-Seitz grid point
ALLOCATE (ndegen(num_nrpt))
!

!Allocating the array to store Hamiltonian matrix information in 'wannier90_hr.dat' file
ALLOCATE (hr(num_wan**2*num_nrpt,7))
!

!Reading the degeneracy of each Wigner-Seitz grid point and the Hamiltonian matrix information in 'wannier90_hr.dat' file
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   IF (MOD(num_nrpt, 15) .EQ. 0) THEN
      DO i = 1, num_nrpt / 15, 1
         READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(i-1)*15:15+(i-1)*15)
      END DO
   ELSE
      DO i = 1, num_nrpt / 15, 1
         READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(i-1)*15:15+(i-1)*15)
      END DO
      READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(num_nrpt/15)*15:num_nrpt)
   END IF
   DO i = 1, num_wan**2*num_nrpt, 1
      READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) hr(i,:)
   END DO

   !Closing 'wannier90_hr.dat' file
   CLOSE (UNIT=4)
   !

   !Converting the unit number into coordinate for R in exponent term of phase factor in tight binding Hamiltonian matrix
   DO i = 1, num_wan**2*num_nrpt, 1
      tra(1) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,1) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,1) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,1)
      tra(2) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,2) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,2) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,2)
      tra(3) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,3) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,3) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,3)
      hr(i,1:3) = tra
   END DO
   !

END IF
!

CALL MPI_BCAST(ndegen,num_nrpt,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(hr,num_wan**2*num_nrpt*7,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

!!!Block 1: Computing berry curvature from Wannier90 code

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=7, FILE='INPUT.dat', STATUS='OLD')

   !Reading the number of k point
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) kb
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) eta
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) fe
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) er
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) sa
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) fq
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) tp
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) th
   !
   !Closing 'wannier90_band.kpt' file
   CLOSE (UNIT=7)
   !

END IF
!

CALL MPI_BCAST(kb,3,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(eta,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(fe,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(er,2,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(sa,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(fq,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(tp,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

!Allocating the array to store the extracted tight binding Hamiltonian matrix
ALLOCATE (ba_tb(num_wan,num_wan))
!

!Allocating the array to store the tight binding Eigen vector matrix
ALLOCATE (ba_evc(num_wan,num_wan))
!

!Allocating the array to store the tight binding Eigen value
ALLOCATE (ba_evl(num_wan))
!

!Allocating array to store the coordinate of k point
ALLOCATE (ba_kp(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),3))
!

!Computing the coordinate of k point
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DO i = 1, kb(1), 1
      DO j = 1, kb(2), 1
         DO k = 1, kb(3), 1
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,1) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(i-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(1))
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,2) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(j-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(2))
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,3) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(k-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(3))
         END DO
       END DO
   END DO

   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
      tra(1) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,1) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,1) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,1)
      tra(2) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,2) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,2) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,2)
      tra(3) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,3) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,3) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,3)
      ba_kp(i,:) = tra
   END DO

   IF (kb(1) /= 1) THEN
      dk(1) = DSQRT(rec_cons(1,1)**2+rec_cons(1,2)**2+rec_cons(1,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(1)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(1) = 1.0d0
   END IF
   IF (kb(2) /= 1) THEN
      dk(2) = DSQRT(rec_cons(2,1)**2+rec_cons(2,2)**2+rec_cons(2,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(2)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(2) = 1.0d0
   END IF
   IF (kb(3) /= 1) THEN
      dk(3) = DSQRT(rec_cons(3,1)**2+rec_cons(3,2)**2+rec_cons(3,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(3)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(3) = 1.0d0
   END IF

END IF
!

CALL MPI_BCAST(ba_kp,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

!Allocating array to store the berry curvature at each k point on each processor
ALLOCATE (bcp1(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),9))
!

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   !Allocating array to store the berry curvature at each k point on root processor
   ALLOCATE (bcp2(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),9))
   bcp2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   !

   !Allocating array to store the berry curvature at each k point on other processor
   ALLOCATE (bcp3(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),9))
   bcp3 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   !
END IF

!Building Hamiltonian on all k points and Computing the berry Curvature
ba_tb = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
   IF (MOD(i-1,world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
   kp = ba_kp(i,:)
   CALL CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT(i,ndegen,num_wan,num_nrpt,kp,hr,ba_tb,ba_evc,ba_evl,eta,fe,er,pi,sa,fq,tp,hb,bcp1)
   IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
      bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp1
      DO j = 1, world_size-1, 1
         IF (i-1+j == kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)) EXIT
         k = i + j + 1000
         CALL MPI_RECV(bcp3,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)*6,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,j,k,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
         bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp3
      END DO
   ELSE
      k = i + 1000
      CALL MPI_SEND(bcp1,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)*6,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,k,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   END IF
END DO
!

CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   !Coefficient
   cf = pi * el * el * el / hb / hb / (rea_cons(i,1)*rea_cons(i,2)*th)
   !
   br = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1 !This is error line 318.
      br = br + bcp2(i,:)
   END DO
   OPEN (UNIT=8, FILE='circularphotogalvaniceffect.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(A22)') 'xxy, xxz, xyz, yxy, yxz, yyz, zxy, zxz, zyz'
   WRITE(UNIT=8, FMT=*) cf * br * dk(1) * dk(2) * dk(3)
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*)
   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(3(F12.8,3X))') ba_kp(i,:)
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*) cf * bcp2(i,:) * dk(1) * dk(2) * dk(3)
   END DO
END IF

!Stopping timer
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(ti(2))
   WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT='(A,F15.8)') 'Time for all (seconds):', (ti(2) - ti(1)) / ra
END IF
!

DEALLOCATE (ba_tb)
DEALLOCATE (ba_kp)
DEALLOCATE (ba_evc)
DEALLOCATE (ba_evl)
DEALLOCATE (bcp1)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DEALLOCATE (bcp2)
   DEALLOCATE (bcp3)
   CLOSE (UNIT=8)
END IF

!Finalising MPI
CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
!



!!!End Block 1



DEALLOCATE (ndegen)
DEALLOCATE (hr)

STOP
END PROGRAM
```

I do not understand why the 318th line 'DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1' is wrong.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran], Fortran 90 is only one particular very old revision of the standard. To get a more meaningful backtrace use the `-g` compiler flag. To enable error bound checking use `-check -warn` in Intel Fortran or `-fcheck=all -Wall` in gfortran. Please recompile your code with these options and show us the result. Don't forget to tell us which lines of code belong to line numbers that will appear in the messages.

Comment: @Vladimir I label the error line with the line number 318.

Comment: @Vladimir This is the compiling information. 'Loading compilers-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading tbb-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading mkl-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading compilers-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading tbb-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading tbb-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
Loading mpi-2021.3.0 version modulefiles
The job  is running on'

Comment: I suspect your problem is line 315, where you're using `i` outside of any `i` loop.

Comment: Note also `MPI_INT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are not part of the Fortran MPI binding  -you probably mean `MPI_INTEGER` and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`

Comment: @Kieran Yes, I did notice that line 318 is indicated in the backtrace but most is obscured. And line 318 is probably not even the critical one.  Please really do try those compiler options and get used to use them every time when developing any Fortran code. I think the problem indicated by veryreverie is is probably the right one, but correct use of compiler error-checking options should reveal that for you without having to ask.

Comment: @veryreverie Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, it is wrong variable that I did not give the value.

Comment: @Ian Bush Thank you for the suggestion. I will write the full type name of the variable.

Comment: @Vladimir Sure. I will keep this warning option in the compiling script. Thank you.